# Selecting a Function Value Shows nvarchar(4000) on an Index

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, indexing, non-clustered-index

I have a view that I'm trying to setup an Index for. One of the select columns for the view executes a user-defined function that has a return value of varchar(250). However, when I try to setup an Index on that column, I see a size of nvarchar(4000). Why is that and will that cause a problem if I continue to setup my index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does running `sp_refreshview 'YourViewName'` resolve the issue? (I think you will need to change the view to use `WITH SCHEMABINDING` as well)

Answer (score 0):

i think your main suggestion here is going to be to ditch the scalar udf.  they're an awful performance drag.  is there a legitimate business reason for the udf?

pull the code out of the scalar function and place it inside of the view directly and see if that alleviates your problem.

Comment: It's not a drag. The UDF itself does some data manipulation. I don't want to have that in 6 different spots in a single view especially at nearly 100 lines.